# Can a space station theoretically maintain an orbit around two separate astronomical bodies? Switching between the two cyclically?

Tags: space, science-fiction, science-in-society

Would this type of orbit be possible to achieve without external forces being applied? Is it possible at all? I have little to no background in the sciences so please explain like I'm stupid. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31201/might-a-planet-perform-figure-8-orbits-around-two-stars

Comment: @H.Mallory But note that an orbit that's too unstable for a planet can work just fine for a space station, since it only has to stay in the orbit for years rather than billions of years, and it can adjust its orbit slightly from time to time.

Comment: Thats a good point Mike. This gives me a lot to work with. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 5):

This is called the 3-body problem.  You can find depicted a number of stable orbits.  Here is one in 2d that I like.

from http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/chaos/3body.htm
[image: 2d depiction of stable 3-body orbit]

There is a collection of 3-body orbits in this bizarre site. http://three-body.ipb.ac.rs/

The pictures are pretty 
[image]

but the text appears very, very slowly...

Answer (score 3):

That orbit is possible, if unstable (would need active correction from space station).

You would also be interested to [Low Energy Transfer Orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-energy_transfer) where you can plan a trip between several bodies (planets or, more easily moons) by switching orbit at certain exchange points.

These orbits are "slow" if compared with other solutions, including the classical [Hohmann Transfer Orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit), but require very low impulse, perhaps compatible with Space Station attitude engines.